# Parsing Json Array from Json Object shows only first item in the list Java

Tags: java, arrays, json

I'm trying to parse list of array from json object like below code,

```
File file = new File(HomePage.jsonFilePath);
if (file.exists()) {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    try {
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(file));
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        System.out.println("Customer json for config customer " + jsonObject.toString());
        configuredBranch = (String) jsonObject.get("branch");
        configuredSystem = (String) jsonObject.get("system");
        expinContainerPath = (String) jsonObject.get("path");
        if (isEditable) {
            try {
                JSONArray customerArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("customer_list");
                if (customerArray != null && customerArray.size() > 0) {
                    Iterator<String> iterator = customerArray.iterator();
                    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        System.out.println("customer gson" + iterator.next());
                        customerList.add(iterator.next());
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And the console shows the below json when executing this line **System.out.println("Customer json for config customer "+jsonObject.toString());**

```
{"path":"C:\\Users\\Documents","system":"Exp","customer_list":["test","test1"],"branch":"LRD"}
```

But while iterating and printing like below **System.out.println("customer gson"+iterator.next());** Its always prints test i.e first item in customer_list. I want to display all items in "customer_list". Could you please suggest me any idea to do this? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call the iterator's `next()` method twice inside the `while` loop, call it only once instead. So, rewrite your code:

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String customer = iterator.next();
    System.out.println("Customer " + customer);
    customerList.add(customer);
}
```